# Finding Add To Cart button with selenium using find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a function that locates any add to cart button on a given website by searching for the text on the button. For example, Amazon says "Add To Cart" so I am using this function to try to locate the button. Unfortunately I'm getting:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[.='Add To Cart']"}

```
def GetElementByText(driver, url, text):
    driver.get(url)
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='" + text + "']")
    print(element)
    return element

element = GetElementByText(driver, 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZG9U0KA?pf_rd_r=AQC5SP1PPERA8C37YCC8&pf_rd_p=5ae2c7f8-e0c6-4f35-9071-dc3240e894a8', 'Add To Cart')
```

I've also tried using this function, which works on other websites but not on Amazon.

```
def GetButtons(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    driver.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    buttons = soup.find_all('button')
    return buttons

GetButtons(driver, 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00ZG9U0KA?pf_rd_r=AQC5SP1PPERA8C37YCC8&pf_rd_p=5ae2c7f8-e0c6-4f35-9071-dc3240e894a8')
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this in a dynamic way that would be easy to apply to other websites? My concern is that some websites have buttons, and some have links. Returning all the links or tags using BeautifulSoup returns too many results to practically sort through.

Any ideas for how to accomplish this? The function wouldn't necessarily have to automatically find the button on its own (Though that would be great), but if I could narrow it down enough to search through 10-20 possible results that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

1. On Amazon, the text is "Add to Cart" with a lowercase "to," you have it as an uppercase "To."
2. By changing your xpath to `"//*[.='" + text + "']"`, I was able to find it (after correcting the To/to error). It might be too broad for general application, but worth a try.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I overlooked that for the last several hours. That works perfectly.